# Is it safe to purge nodejs when replacing "/usr/bin/nodejs" with "/usr/local/bin/node"?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, apt, node.js, packages

System - Raspbian (Jessie):

`sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable`

Now I have two instances of node.

`/usr/bin/node -v` returns `v0.10.29`

`/usr/local/bin/node -v` returns `v6.2.1`

**Question:**

`sudo apt-get purge nodejs` has a laundry list of packages that will be removed. Is it safe to purge these dependencies? Is the instance in `/usr/local/bin` self-contained or does it rely on these pre-existing packages? Will node red still work?

Answer (score 1):

So I ran:
`sudo apt-get purge nodejs`

Unfortunately, it did impact my ability to call `node -v`.

I was able to find where all the symbolic links using:

`sudo find / -name "node" | less`

Then I removed them and created a new one using:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.2.2/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node`

Now `node -v` returns `v6.2.2` as expected.

**EDIT:**

Afterward, my Pi was having difficulty locating node pacakages I installed. I was able to remedy this by adding `/usr/local/n/versions/node/6.2.2/bin` to my `$PATH` environment variable.

To test if it will work for you (without making permanent changes), you can simply type.

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/n/versions/node/6.2.2/bin`

If that worked, then you can permanently update your path variable by editing `/etc/profile`; the file where the `$PATH` variable gets set.

`sudo nano /etc/profile`

*NOTE: You will need to replace `6.2.2` with your current version of node*

Answer (score 0):

I purged the original Node.js that comes pre-installed with the Pi and installed Node.js myself.  The purge did indeed remove Node-RED and other Node based tools.  After I installed the latest Node.js I then manually installed the packages I needed (such as Node-RED).  I suffered no ill effects and ended up with exactly the set of installed packages at the correct levels that I wanted.  My recommendation is to note the packages that are removed by a Node.js purge and decide which of them you want to have again.

I use Node.js extensively on the Pi and there has been no ill effects on me following this procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it gave me the courage to pull the trigger! I recorded my experience as a more specific answer for others.